# Configuration LDAP for ImportExportService with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: ldap, content-porter

I'm facing a problem that LDAP authentication for ImportExportService(Content Porter) doesn't work. I have already configured LDAP authentication for TCM, so I can log in TCM.

When I login  to Content Porter, Content Porter client say the following message.

> Could not find SDL Tridion Content Manager server myservername. Please
>   verify that the server is up and running.

And the following message is output to event log.

> Access is denied for the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport
>   Errorcode: 770
>   User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> StackTrace Information Details:
>     at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, IEnumerable`1 mappedGroupUris, IEnumerable`1 claimSets)
>     at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor()
>     at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.SessionHelper.GetCurrentSession()
>     at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Service.ImportExportServiceBase.TestConnection()
>     at SyncInvokeTestConnection(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

I tried two pattern setting of webservices/web.config as follows, but I couldn't login.

CASE A

> ```
>    <binding name="ImportExport_StreamDownload_basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483648" transferMode="StreamedResponse" messageEncoding="Mtom" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
>      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
>        <!-- For LDAP or SSO authentication of transport credentials, use clientCredentialType="None" -->
>        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
>      </security>
>    </binding>
> ```

CASE B (clientCredentialType was set to None)

> ```
>    <binding name="ImportExport_StreamDownload_basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483648" transferMode="StreamedResponse" messageEncoding="Mtom" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
>      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
>        <!-- For LDAP or SSO authentication of transport credentials, use clientCredentialType="None" -->
>        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
>      </security>
>    </binding>
> ```

Could you please tell me what I should do?

Environment:
Tridion 2013 SP1
Content Porter 2013 SP1
Windows 2008 R2 SP1 + MSSQL 2008 R2 SP2

Regards

Comment: I am also facing similar problem even though everything has configure as required in this post. Anyone have any solution on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure the steps needed for Content Porter configuration with LDAP? Please check the Tridion docs and follow these steps : http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3AB5898C-743B-4B4B-BE8B-46F1C0CDD300

Please note, these are additional steps needed for Content Porter in addition to the CM so you need to first make sure CMS UI working correctly with LDAP and then follow these steps for Content Porter.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have already finished Content Porter configuration with LDAP.

I have enabled anonymous access on the ImportExportService and ImportExportService\client virtual directories.
SDL Tridion Content Manager configuration have been configured for using LDAP, so Impersonation User setting have been already set to 'Directory Service'.
Regarding Urls without HTTP authentication, New value '|(ImportExportService/Client)' have been set when I installed Content Porter 2013 SP1.

Do I have anything to check?

Answer (score 2):

Since 2013 SP1 Content Porter Core part is placed in Tridion Core (TcmServiceHost + IIS).
Your stack trace shows, that there is problem on creating session (impersonation).
Look here http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-20723F2E-686D-44AC-835A-8F84A5DD7A22#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DLDAP&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1395735753185&currentQuery=LDAP&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5EF9CE54-A864-4CE2-A61C-9F7DF97902B3&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-5EF9CE54-A864-4CE2-A61C-9F7DF97902B3.xml

PS: usually problems with CP connection were related to 8D. Earlier this point was missed in the documentation

PPS: Looked again...There are can be additional problems with configuration of CP. But for now your problem is simpler - CoreService is not working with LDAP Authentication.